# Joomla 2.5 method save()

Tags: methods, joomla, save

Is there a way to show the changed values after saving within the Joomla save method?
For example, when I edit a "maxuser" field and save it, I´d like to show the old and the new value. 
I tried this by comparing "getVar" and "$post", but both values are the same.

```
function save()
{

...

$maxuser1 = JRequest::getVar('maxuser');
$maxuser2 = $post['maxuser'];

...
if($maxuser1 != $maxuser2) {
    $msg = "Not the same ...";
}

...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to override `JTable`, not the Model. Heres sample code:

```
public function store($updateNulls = false) {
  $oldTable = JTable::getInstance(TABLE_NAME, INSTANCE_NAME);
  $messages = array();
  if ($oldTable->load($this->id)) {        
    // Now you can compare any values where $oldTable->param is old, and $this->param is new
    // For example
    if ($oldTable->title != $this->title) {
      $messages[] = "Title has changed";
    }
  }

  $result = parent::store($updateNulls);

  if ((count($messages) > 0) && ($result === true)){
    $message = implode("\n", $messages);
    return $message;
  } else {
    return $result;
  }    
}
```

This will return message string if there are any, `true` if there are no messages and save succeeded and `false` if saving failed. So all you have to do is check returned value in model and set right redirect message.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller you can use the postSaveHook which gives you access to the validated values.

Comment: But postSave you don't have values, which were before saving. Or am i wrong?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found an easier solution. I added a hidden field in my form, so now I can compare JRequest::getVar('maxuserold') and $post['maxuser'].

Comment: @i3sel Sure you have the old values, that's what the OP is saying, he has the old ones, he needs the new ones to compare. shadylane use JInput rather than JRequest; JRequest is deprecated.